# convert c-style-sting to std::string inside initialization list of a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, stdstring, c-strings

Is it safe to convert `char*` to `std::string` inside initialization list of a constructor like below:

```
class MyClass{
public:
MyClass(){}
MyClass(
    char*char_Ptr_Definition_File
    ,char*char_Ptr_Parameters_File
    ,char*char_Ptr_Response_File
    ,char*char_Ptr_Work_Dir
    )
    :
    m_string_Definition_File(std::string(char_Ptr_Definition_File))
    ,m_string_Parameters_File(std::string(char_Ptr_Parameters_File))
    ,m_string_Response_File(std::string(char_Ptr_Response_File))
    ,m_string_Work_Dir(std::string(char_Ptr_Work_Dir))
{
}
private:
    std::string m_string_Definition_File;
    std::string m_string_Parameters_File;
    std::string m_string_Response_File;
    std::string m_string_Work_Dir;
};
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  You can create a string from a `char*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe as long as the `char*` point to a null-terminated string. You don't need to be as verbose though. This would be fine:

```
m_string_Definition_File(char_Ptr_Definition_File)
```

You may also choose to protect against null pointers, for example by setting the string to be empty:

```
m_string_Definition_File(char_Ptr_Definition_File ?
                         char_Ptr_Definition_File :
                         "")
```

and so on. But this applies to initializing strings from `char*` in general.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming the `char*` string is null terminated.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

The fourth constructor listed in that link takes a `const char*`, and "**Copies** the null-terminated character sequence (C-string) pointed by s".

Therefore once the `std::string` has been initialised from the `char*`, either can be modified or destroyed without affecting the other.